# Change a prop value inside functional component can cause problems in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I receive a prop and change it in my functional component, can it create a problem? Or it's ok to change it inside the component?

e.g

```
const MyComponent = ({ foo }) => {

    // is this bad?
    foo = someCondition ? bar : foo

    return (...)
}
```

I know that I could create another variable and store the values, but I would like to know if changing the prop it self won't cause any problem because it's a functional component.

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't create any problems. As with regular functions the arguments passed are their own variables in the function scope and don't mutate the original value passed to the function.

```js
function something(value) {
  value = 'nothing';
}

var anything = 0;
something(anything);

// Anything should still be 0;
console.log(anything);
```

But I would suggest to **not** mutate your variables.

Answer (score 2):

If foo in your example is passed from the parrent, and the parrent keeps it in its state, then you would also need to pass setFoo as a paramater to your component and use that to update it properly.

```
function Parrent(){  
  let [foo, setFoo] = useState('foo');  
  return <Child foo={foo} setFoo={setFoo}/>
}
```

As for changing the props directly, you can if they are arrays or objects.

Answer (score 1):

Props in the React are just read-only variables. You should change the props values by the parent component

Answer (score 1):

I avoid changing the prop. 
But I created a simple example and changing the prop in the children do not affected the value in the parent component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-cdn-cq55d

I tested it with several render. Thats why I added an input. Typing in it makes the component rerender.

Answer (score 1):

```
const MyComponent = ({ foo }) => {

    // Not valid
    foo = someCondition ? bar : foo

    return (...)
}
```

There are two kinds of data in React,

> `a)Props(immutable data) 
>    b)State(mutable data)`

you are not supposed to change the immutable data(there are some ways to do it, but not recommended). what you should do is, (you can't assign a callback and change from here, i'll explain later why)

if you want to just use just the value inside this component

```
const baz = foo === condition ? bar : foo
```

or render something based on foo meets some condition

```
return (
 <div>
  {foo === somecondition ? <A /> : <B />}
 </div>

 )
```

Or you want to actually change it,

coming from a global state like redux or mobx,

> u should change it from the reducers in case of redux or
>   @action decorated functions in mobx.

if it's a local state which passed down to the child component,

u can set a call back and assign to a click handler in which the case it is feasible

```
handleClick = () => {
 this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  foo: someCondition ? bar : foo,
 }))
}

render () {
 const { handleClick } = this

 return <ChildComponent {...{ handleClick }} />
}
```

Like said before u can't change the passed down local state from render of the child(or render of any component[actually u can, but may end up in infinite loops: each time a state change happens, the component will re render, so the loop(pure components excluded eg: shouldComponentUpdate() hook which validates an unrelated condition)])

in such cases what u should do is to **make the child component also a stateful component and change the parent props with a callback**

```
class Child extends Component {
 //set once 
 componentWillMount() {
  if (condition) callback
 }

 //whenever there is change
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (condition) callback
 }

 //use correct lifecycle method which meets your requirement..
}
```